# Angular CLI; Focus also scrolls to input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll) to scroll the page at certain points in my app. Everything was working well until I added this line that should happen at the same time as the page scroll.

```
this.myInput.first.nativeElement.focus()
```

This caused the `focus()` to race the page scroll. Since I am giving the page scroll call a `pageScrollDuration` and the `focus()` apparently scrolls with a duration of 0, the page jumps to the `input` instead of smoothly scrolling there.

How do I make sure the page scroll smoothly scrolls to the element while still focusing on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I was able to find was to wrap the

`this.myInput.first.nativeElement.focus()`

with the following:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.myInput.first.nativeElement.focus()
}, 0)
```

This causes the page scroll to happen smoothly.

Comment: Can't you use the `pageScrollFinish` event provided by the library to trigger focus then?

Comment: I looked into this, the problem with it was that the element being focused is not in the same component as the component in charge of scrolling.